# Owl Carousel select current item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I want to select Owl Carousel 2 current item. 
How am I gonna do that? Please Help!

There is two center classed item in carousel 
i'have tried this

```
$.each(centerItems, function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('cloned')) {
        centerItem = $(this);
    }
});
```

but it not works correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm basing this answer on the demo on the [Owl Carousel 2 homepage](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/). To get the active items, do this:

```
$('.owl-carousel .owl-item.active')
```

where `.owl-carousel` is the carousel container and `.owl-item` is the item class.

If this doesn't work, please post your HTML code.